# How to check if a Vector's size exist?

Tags: java, vector

I would like to check if a Vector's size exists and equals 0.

I thought of using the following:

```
if (vector1 != null && vector1.size() == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: you can also use `isEmpty()` instead. If you still want to compare for equality then use == and not =. Didn't you get an error from the compiler?

Comment: I mistakenly forgot to use ==

Comment: @Dhmhgr13 - What problem are you facing? Isn't your code giving you the correct result? Did you try the alternative function suggested by Joakim Danielson?

Answer (score 0):

vector1.size() doesn't take and parameter and return the number of element present in the vector.